# Etymology of "card" referring to an eccentric person

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the use of the word "card" to refer to an eccentric person?  How did this meaning develop?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The earliest recorded use of [card](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-car3.htm) in this sense was in an [1836](http://www.theanswerbank.co.uk/Phrases-and-Sayings/Word-Origins/Question937524.html) work by Dickens (Sketches By Boz) in which he referred to someone as "a knowing card" ("Mr. Thomas Potter whose great aim it was to be considered as a 'knowing card'".) He used it again in Bleak House in 1852: “Such an old card has this; so deep, so sly, and secret.” This usage sprang from cards in the sense of playing cards, which had long used such phrases as a sure card, a safe card, a best card and so on. *Cards* were used for playing cards at least from Late Middle English, from Old French carte, from Latin carta, charta, from Greek khartēs 'papyrus leaf.

Earlier, in the 1500s on, a *good card* was used, but this probably (my guess, not official) referred to *carded wool*, where a *good card*  meant a carding job on fleece that resulted in a clean, litter-free batch of carded wool. There are references to thistles and combs with *card*, which would also be in the manner of *carding wool*.

Another [source](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/57/messages/830.html) wherein *card* (alone) was used to indicate a witty or eccentric person, a "character," puts the first usage at 1911 in *The Card*, a novel by Arnold Bennett.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right. My initial guess (as "armchair etymologist") was that it would relate to the *Joker* playing card in a deck (i.e. - an *unpredictable* character). But as you (and OED) say, it appears to derive from almost the exact opposite (a ***sure** card*, first attested by OED 1560). Live and learn!

Comment: In all my life, up until the day I posted this question, I had never heard "card" being used in this sense.  Is this usage common to any particular part of the world?

Comment: @Paul - in the US, it was quite common, say, 40 years ago and back from there, but has fallen out of popular use since then. I used to say it to my kids. :)

Comment: Dialectical note, my mother (born 1958) still uses this a lot, so it survives in at least one part of Appalachia in at least one person

Comment: "He's a right card" and "he's a card alright" still seem to be current according to a cursory google search. But I don't think I've said either in the last 20 years. @Paul I would say they were very common idioms.

Answer (score 0):

My family use it a lot and I don’t know if it has a Cornish background. Referring to someone who is very amusing

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is more of a commentary than a real answer for the question. A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. The question is asking about the etymology and history of the word's usage. Please consider expanding your answer.